# How can I match two rows to two different rows in Excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

EDIT: I got it to work)

(I hope this explanation is better than my asked question, I did not know how to word it better!)

I have columns A and B. These are matches. I now have column C. All the numbers in C are numbers from A, but randomized. Imagine A has 2500+ numbers and of course matching B cells. I need every cell in D to find the value of the number in its adjacent place.

For example:

D1 needs to be "C", because A5 has "C" next to it.
D2 needs to be "A", because A2 has "A" next to it.

I made this example only 5 rows long, but I can't do this by myself with more than 2500 rows.
Is there a way that I can let Excel look through columns A and B, find the right value for the D cells and match them?

The correct order (for this example) will be

5C

1A

3B

2A

4C

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A simple `VLOOKUP` should do what you want.  Take a look at Excel HELP for examples.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I know it has something to do with VLOOKUP but I just can't get it to work.. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Edit your post to show the formula that you used; what you got for a result; and what you expected.

Comment: Alright! It worked! I will edit the post with my solution. Thanks again @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Please don't edit the question with the answer. you can answer your own question and mark your answer as correct. That way people will know it is answered correctly

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution!

=VLOOKUP(C:C;A:B;2;FALSE)